# Change Date to 00:00:00 format

Tags: javascript, typescript

Database holds timestamps in this format - `03:59:59`. Also I use third party plugin (autocomplete box) and it returns Date objects. I managed to use data from database in my plugin like below:

```
if (value) {
    let splitTime = value.split(':')
    date = new Date()
    // If ...splitTime (spread operator) is used in below, compiler throws exeption - "Expected 1 or 4 arguments but got 0 or more" (I consider it as TS bug)
    date.setHours(splitTime[0], splitTime[1], splitTime[2]);
    // now I can use date string in my plugin
}
```

Are there any simple ways to transform Date object to `00:00:00` format? As I start it appears to look ugly:

`'' + args.value.getHours() + ':' + args.value.getMinutes() + ':' + args.value.getSeconds())`

Result is still not what is needed:

> //=> 3:59:59

(notice - 3 is not 03)

Comment: try this : `("0"+args.value.getHours()).slice(-2)`

Comment: [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @ Terry Wei  yes  that would solve it. I'll use it if no better options will be provided

Comment: if you are looking for a plugin https://momentjs.com/ is a powerful one

Comment: I use the string concatenation like you did, but with a call to a zero fill function (minutes and seconds can be < 10 too). Using momentjs for merely that formatting is awkward.

Comment: Thanks, but plugin is not the option at this stage (no other needs except this one)

Comment: maybe you have a look to this function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I commented:

```js
function formatDate(date) {

    return (('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2) +
        ':' +
        ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) +
        ':' +
        ('0' + date.getSeconds()).slice(-2));
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date(2018, 6, 21, 1, 1, 1)));
```